# Delete from folder and database. Codeintiger

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My Controller file:

```php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Image extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
     {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('Image_model');
     }
     public function index()
     {
      $this->load->view('image_upload');
     }
     // add image from form
     public function add_image()
     {
      // CI form validation
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('image_name', 'Image Name', 'required');
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
       $this->load->view('image_upload');
            }
      else {
       // configurations from upload library
       $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
       $config['max_size'] = '2048000'; // max size in KB
       $config['max_width'] = '20000'; //max resolution width
       $config['max_height'] = '20000';  //max resolution height
       // load CI libarary called upload
       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       // body of if clause will be executed when image uploading is failed
       if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // This image is uploaded by deafult if the selected image in not uploaded
        $image = 'no_image.png';    
       }
       // body of else clause will be executed when image uploading is succeeded
       else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  //name must be userfile
        
       }
       $this->Image_model->insert_image($image);
       $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Image stored');
       redirect('Image');
      }
     }
     // view images fetched from database
     public function view_images()
     {
      $data['images'] = $this->Image_model->get_images();
      $this->load->view('image_view', $data);
     }
       public function delete($image_id){ 
            // Check whether id is not empty 
            if($image_id){ 
                $galleryData = $this->image_data->getRows($image_id); 
                 
                // Delete gallery data 
                $delete = $this->image_data->delete($image_id); 
                 
                if($delete){ 
                    // Delete images data  
                    $condition = array('image_id' => $image_id);  
                    $deleteImg = $this->image_data->deleteImage($condition);  
                      
                    // Remove files from the server  
                    if(!empty($galleryData['images'])){  
                        foreach($galleryData['images'] as $img){  
                            @unlink('uploads/images/'.$img['image']);  
                        }  
                    }  
                     
                    $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg', 'Gallery has been removed successfully.'); 
                }else{ 
                    $this->session->set_userdata('error_msg', 'Some problems occurred, please try again.'); 
                } 
            } 
     
            redirect($this->controller); 
        } 
    }
```

My model:

```php
    
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Image_model extends CI_Model {
     public function insert_image($image)
     {
      // assign the data to an array
      $data = array(
       'image_id' => $this->input->post('image_id'),
       'image_name' => $this->input->post('image_name'),
       'image' => $image
      );
      //insert image to the database
      $this->db->insert('image_data', $data);
     }
     //get images from database
     public function get_images()
     {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->order_by('image_id');
      $query = $this->db->get('image_data');
      return $query->result();
     }
      public function delete($image_id){ 
            // Delete gallery data 
            $delete = $this->db->delete($this->image_data, array('id' => $image_id)); 
             
            // Return the status 
            return $delete?true:false; 
        } 
         
    }
```

My views `image_upload.php`

```php
    <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Image upload</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">CodeIgniter Image Upload</h2>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- success message to display after uploading image -->
              <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) {?>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
                  </div>
              <?php  } ?> 
              <!-- validation message to display after form is submitted -->
                 <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>','</div>');
                 ?>    
                 <!-- image upload form      -->
                 <?php echo form_open_multipart('Image/add_image') ?>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Image Name</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image_name" name="image_name">
                     </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Image</label>
                       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="userfile" name="userfile">
                     </div>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
                 <?php form_close() ?> 
    
                 <a href="<?php echo site_url('Image/view_images') ?>" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 20px;">View Images</a>  
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery CDN -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap JS links -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My `image_view.php`

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Image upload</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">CodeIgniter Image Upload</h2>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- success message to display after uploading image -->
              <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) {?>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
                  </div>
              <?php  } ?> 
              <!-- validation message to display after form is submitted -->
                 <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>','</div>');
                 ?>    
                 <!-- image upload form      -->
                 <?php echo form_open_multipart('Image/add_image') ?>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Image Name</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image_name" name="image_name">
                     </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Image</label>
                       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="userfile" name="userfile">
                     </div>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
                 <?php form_close() ?> 
    
                 <a href="<?php echo site_url('Image/view_images') ?>" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 20px;">View Images</a>  
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery CDN -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap JS links -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am able to upload but pls let me know the process to delete from the database and folder. When I try to delete it shows an error -

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Cannot use
> object of type stdClass as array

Please update the delete portion code so that it deletes both from the database and folder.

> Database - ci_image
> Table - image_data column - image_id, image_name,image

Comment: What is the line number of error?

Comment: Filename: F:\XAMPP\htdocs\learn\application\views\image_view.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:

File: F:\XAMPP\htdocs\learn\application\controllers\Image.php
Line: 51
Function: view

File: F:\XAMPP\htdocs\learn\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: How are you calling delete function and where does $this->image_data comes from?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url('Image/delete/'.$row['image_id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger" >delete</a>
 image_data is the table name.

Comment: where did you declared $image_data in model and controller?

Answer (score 0):

You have add this code in your controller:

```
 unlink(FCPATH ."uploads/images/".$img['image']); //To delete file from the folder
    
   $this->Image_model->delete($image_id); //To delete file from the database
```

Note: please note you need to add correct path inside unlink() .